# Getting all the parents based on submission in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me out how to get all parents for submissions. If I pass `submissionId` to the table (highlighted in black), I should get all parents for that submission (highlighted in red)

[image]

Sample data:

```
5EAB0B3D-5A17-43A9-9BC2-21B950F4B4E7    24A6DB20-20D1-4063-9DC6-CC1990B26FD7
4DEA6377-DF7C-415E-8E06-7DDEB34B53F6    45D6A438-61C7-488C-BC83-8AAB491B037D
9B83B4D0-E122-462F-842D-9A0A4774A6D5    24A6DB20-20D1-4063-9DC6-CC1990B26FD7
0BED1600-3120-4C3A-BA86-A3BFAC5765FA    9B83B4D0-E122-462F-842D-9A0A4774A6D5
DB5DF89E-0E6B-46FE-BE9A-CA6F47F4B544    24A6DB20-20D1-4063-9DC6-CC1990B26FD7
```

Query:

```
WITH n([submissionid], [parentid]) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [submissionid], 
        [parentid] 
    FROM   
        [submissionrenewal] 
    WHERE  
        [submissionid] = '0BED1600-3120-4C3A-BA86-A3BFAC5765FA' 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        m.[submissionid], 
        m.[parentid] 
    FROM   
        [submissionrenewal] AS m, 
        n 
    WHERE  
        n.[submissionid] = m.[parentid]
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM n
```

Input

```
0BED1600-3120-4C3A-BA86-A3BFAC5765FA
```

Output

```
9B83B4D0-E122-462F-842D-9A0A4774A6D5 
24A6DB20-20D1-4063-9DC6-CC1990B26FD7
```

Comment: Post sample data as text.. Never post the sample data as image nobody can use it test the code..

Comment: posted, data let me know if there is a way i can attach it

Comment: Its enough also add the expected result for sample data.. Heard about `Recursive CTE` in Sql Server ?

Comment: i have tried this but did not get any result

Comment: Post the query and expected result in question

Comment: You just need to change the join condition. `Parentid` from anchor query should be joined with `submissionid` recursive part. You have to just exchange the alias name in `where` clause `m.[submissionid] = n.[parentid]`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thank you marc, will follow, i am still a kid in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the join condition. `Parentid` from anchor query should be joined with `submissionid` recursive part. You have to just exchange the alias name in `where` clause `m.[submissionid] = n.[parentid]`

```
WITH n([submissionid], [parentid]) -- giving a meaningful CTE name will improve the code readability  
     AS (SELECT [submissionid], 
                [parentid] 
         FROM   [submissionrenewal] 
         WHERE  [submissionid] = '0BED1600-3120-4C3A-BA86-A3BFAC5765FA' 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT m.[submissionid], 
                m.[parentid] 
         FROM   [submissionrenewal] AS m 
                INNER JOIN n 
                        ON m.[submissionid] = n.[parentid]) --here
SELECT * 
FROM   n
```

**Note :** Always use `INNER JOIN` syntax instead of old style comma separated join